Why does az monitor app-insights try to encode with cp1252?
I'm trying to retrieve some app-insights, so I issue a basic query
$QUERY = @"
traces
| where timestamp >= ago(1h)
| order by timestamp desc, itemId asc
| limit 2
"@
$resultJson = az monitor app-insights query --app $APP_ID --analytics-query $QUERY

I get this warning
WARNING: Unable to encode the output with cp1252 encoding. Unsupported characters are discarded.

I see that this in only a warning, but I'm trying to troubleshoot why I get hundreds of log entries, even though I've asked for only two.
I've also tried to set the encoding:
$env:AZURE_CLI_ENCODING = "UTF-8"

Any pointers as to what I can try?;)

Firstly, there is no issue with the CLI script approach you are doing. And also setting the encoding format as$env:AZURE_CLI_ENCODING = "UTF-8" is also a right approach.

WARNING: Unable to encode the output with cp1252 encoding:

As you are still facing the conflict here, you can try set the encoding as
[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8 detailed in this SO post.

Why I get hundreds of log entries, even though I've asked for only two:

Instead of using limit operator, try using a take operator which is equivalent to the limit operator in kql.
It will also return up to the specified number of rows as mentioned.

The take and limit operators are equivalent.

I have tried the below way to meet the requirements and was able to achieve it successfully.
traces
| where timestamp >= ago(1h)
| order by timestamp desc, itemId asc
| take 2

Add --output Json to the end of the CLI command as shown below.
$APP_ID="xxxxx"
$resultJson = az monitor app-insights query --app $APP_ID --analytics-query $QUERY --output Json


If still the issue persists, try passing the query along with the
--analytics-query parameter directly instead of storing it in the variable.
az monitor app-insights query --app "b7xxxae67b" --analytics-query 'traces | where timestamp >= ago(1h) | order by timestamp desc, itemId asc | limit 2'


